# Hide counter on cart Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, cart

How to hide counter when cart is empty? Wordpress - woocommerce - supro theme

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ) ?>" class="cart-contents" id="icon-cart-contents">
        <?php echo wp_kses_post( $icon_cart ); ?>
        <span class="label-item cart-label"><?php echo wp_kses( $cart_html, wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' ) ); ?></span>
        <span class="mini-cart-counter"><?php echo intval( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count ); ?></span>
    </a>
```

Tnx

Answer (score 2):

**Updated:** Add this code at your child theme’s **functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'x_hide_cart' );
function x_hide_cart(){
    if ( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() == 0 ) {
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">.x-menu-item-woocommerce{display: none;}</style>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: do I need to change any part of code, because not work...?

Comment: Have you edit in child theme? and you didn't change class of item?